# Microsoft Translate stopped working in my android app

Tags: android, language-translation, microsoft-translator

I have an app on google Play that uses the Microsoft Translator.  Haven't changed the code in over a  year.  Today it is failing with the following message . . .

java.lang.Exception: [microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation : failed to connect to datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/92.242.140.2 (port 443): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Does anyone have a clue what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataMarket service has been shut down. You have to migrate to Azure Cognitive Services.
Instructions here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-migration-from-dm